# What is the name for this kind of combination problem?

Tags: algorithms, combinations

I have $~n~$ positions to fill. At each position $~i~$, I have $~a_i~$ choices. So totally I have $$\Pi_{i=1}^{n} a_i$$ choices.

I want to know this because I want to search for code to enumerate each choice depending on user-specified $~n~$. But I don't know the name of the problem.

Comment: It's commonly called the multiplication principle.

Comment: @MatthewDaly it seems there are no algorithms to do this. I have to write it myself.

Comment: Look up Section 7.2.1 of Volume 4A of Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming*; specifically, Algorithm M.

Comment: Uh, I come up with a counter-like algorithm. Let Ai be the set of choices for step i. I keep track of n counters for each step and keep adding one to the first step counter, carrying if needed. After adding one, I get a set of indices to Ai and that's what I want.

Comment: @FabioSomenz That's fantastic! Exactly what I want. If only I can read the Knuth book earlier.